# Arduino and hard drive

Tags: arduino-uno

So in a laptop you have a CPU and a hard drive. The hard drive feeds data to the CPU and the CPU executes it. In Arduino you flash the CPU and the "hard drive" is built into it. Is it possible to have a hard drive or SD card feed data into the Arduino to be executed and then feed more data in and so on? If it is possible how is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to have a harddrive or sd card feed data into the Arduino to be executed and then feed more data in and so on. If it is possible how is it done?

A harddrive would be difficult to connect, but an SD card will work just fine.

You can write a sketch that reads data from an SD card. There is library support for both SD and FAT16/32 file systems.

Another interpretation of your question is; is it possible to load a sketch from an SD card. The answer is yes; there are a number of projects that have done that.

Cheers!

Comment: will loading sketches take long and will it reduce the lifespan of the chip?

Comment: Depends on how often you want to update the sketch? It is not a very good idea to load the sketch from SD every time. There should be some logic to when the sketch is updated and should be loaded.